# ServiceController.Start(string[])

Tags: c#

I'm trying to start a service that has a argument that specifies a port number.  For example, using the DOS net I would do the following:

```
net start "SERVICENAME" /"ARGUMENT"
```

How would I do the same in C# using Service.Controller.Start()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var sc = new ServiceController() { Name = "SERVICENAME" };
sc.Start(new string[] { "ARGUMENT" });
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```